# How to filter a pandas dataframe using the result of pandas query of another dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a `pandas` df:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'col_a' : ['a','a', 'b'], 'col_b': [1,2,3]})
df.index = [4,5,6]
```

On this `df` i apply a query:

```
df_subset = df.query('col_a == "b"')
```

Now I have a second dataframe which looks like this:

```
import numpy as np
df_numpy = pd.DataFrame(np.array([0.1,0.2,0.3]))
```

which is like the original `df` but without the "identification" column (`col_a`) and the values are transformed in a way (in this toy example, divided by 10)

I would like to select from the `df_numpy` the same rows that are selected from the `df` after applying the query. In this toy example the 3rd row.

**EDIT**
The tricky part is that the index values between `df_numpy` and `df` are not the same.

Is there a way to do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there are same index values use:

```
print (df_numpy[df_numpy.index.isin(df_subset.index)])    
     0
2  0.3
```

EDIT: One idea is create same index values in both, because same length:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col_a' : ['a','a', 'b'], 'col_b': [1,2,3]})
df.index = [4,5,6]

df_subset = df.reset_index(drop=True).query('col_a == "b"')

df_numpy = pd.DataFrame(np.array([0.1,0.2,0.3]))


print (df_numpy[df_numpy.reset_index(drop=True).index.isin(df_subset.index)])

     0
2  0.3
```

Comment: the index values are not the same unfortunately. i will edit my question

Comment: @quant - So length `df_numpy` and `df` is not same?

Comment: the length is, the index is not